# Bootstrap alignment error message below table row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

How I'm going to make the A text input same row as B text input if there is a error message pop out?

Code:

```html
<table id="facilityTbl" class="col-md-12">
<tr>
 <td>A</td>
 <td>B</td>
</tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text'></td>
        <td><input type='text'><p>error-message</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text'></td>
        <td><input type='text'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text'></td>
        <td><input type='text'></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align` for this, check snippet below:

```css
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
p {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <table id="facilityTbl" class="col-md-12">
  <tr>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type='text'></td>
   <td><input type='text'><p>error-message</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type='text'></td>
   <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type='text'></td>
   <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tables, it will move the controls within the .

But I would have done it differently, like this:

```
<input type='text' class="error" placeholder="error-message here">
```

Working Demo

```css
.error{
 border:solid 1px red;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #ff8383;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #ff8383;
}
```

```html
<table id="facilityTbl" class="col-md-12">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' class="error" placeholder="error-message here">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```